# Simple Kivy App for Bootstrap Algorithm

Tags: python, statistics, matplotlib, kivy

I have a very simlpe app built using Kivy, for performing bootstrap algorithm (statistics). We must input some samples in the form `x1,x2,...,xn` (these will be received as a string `"x1,...,xn"` but then will be transformed into a list of the samples. From these samples, we will perform the bootstrap algorithm to approximate the population's sampling mean distribution.

We have the main widget using `Widget` class, and we put a grid layout of 1 row, 2 columns (left one will be for the options, right one will be the plot of the disribution). For the option grid, we put another 4x4 grid layout, with the last grid be a 3x1 grid layout consisting the buttons for the result.

I wonder if there are better and efficient ways to write the code to perform the app.

---

Example:

[image]

---

Code:

```
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


Window.clearcolor = (0,0.5,0.9,0.1)
Window.size = (800, 400)


#Bootstrap Method:


class BootstrapMethod(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_button = BootstrapButton(text = "Bootstrap")
        self.layout = BootstrapGrid()
        self.options = BootstrapOptions()


class RunButtonLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(rows=3, cols=1)
        self.add_widget(PlotNormed(text="Normed histogram"))
        self.add_widget(PlotActual(text="Actual histogram"))
        self.add_widget(BootstrapButton(text="Run bootstrap"))


class PlotNormed(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        xbars = self.parent.parent.parent.xbars
        if xbars != None:
            self.parent.parent.parent.ax.cla()
            self.parent.parent.parent.ax.hist(xbars, normed = True)
            self.parent.parent.parent.fig.figure.canvas.draw()


class PlotActual(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        xbars = self.parent.parent.parent.xbars
        if xbars != None:
            self.parent.parent.parent.ax.cla()
            self.parent.parent.parent.ax.hist(xbars)
            self.parent.parent.parent.fig.figure.canvas.draw()


class BootstrapButton(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        super().on_release()
        sample_string = self.parent.parent.sample_input.text.split(',')
        self.samples = [float(i) for i in sample_string]
        self.bootstrap_algorithm()

    def bootstrap_algorithm(self):
        xbars = []
        n = int(self.parent.parent.bootstrap_sample.text)
        if n > len(self.samples):
            n = len(self.samples)
        nb = int(self.parent.parent.bootstrap_iteration.text)
        for i in range(nb):
            xbar = sum([random.sample(self.samples, 1)[0] for j in range(n)])/n
            xbars.append(xbar)
        self.parent.parent.parent.xbars = xbars
        self.parent.parent.parent.ax.cla()
        self.parent.parent.parent.ax.hist(xbars)
        self.parent.parent.parent.fig.figure.canvas.draw()


class BootstrapOptions(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(rows=2, cols=2)
        self.sample_input = TextInput(text = "Sample input")
        self.bootstrap_iteration = TextInput(text = "Number of bootstrap iterations")
        self.bootstrap_sample = TextInput(text = "Number of sample for resampling")
        self.run_layout = RunButtonLayout()

        self.add_widget(self.sample_input)
        self.add_widget(self.bootstrap_iteration)
        self.add_widget(self.bootstrap_sample)
        self.add_widget(self.run_layout)


class BootstrapGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(rows=1, cols=2, padding = 5, spacing = 5)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        self.options = BootstrapOptions()
        self.add_widget(self.options)
        self.fig = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(fig)
        self.ax = ax
        self.add_widget(self.fig)
        self.xbars = None



######################################################


class Front(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.bs = BootstrapMethod()
        self.add_widget(self.bs.layout)
        self.bs.layout.size = (800, 400)


class mobilesuitApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Front()
        return root

app = mobilesuitApp()
app.run()
```